# How's the extension of ArrowDB storage managed?

Tags: appcelerator, appcelerator-arrow, arrowdb, appcelerator-acs

I searched now for a time for an answer on that topic and interestingly didn't found anything related. Not from Appcelerator itself and also not directly from the community - so maybe I'm also completely wrong and there's a reason outside why nobody is asking. ;-)

I'm using Appcelerator Studio with a Indie plan and currently I'm also doing some research on ArrowDB, which is very interesting for my future plans. The documentation for pre-built services or handling with custom objects whatever is - in my perspective - very clear and understandable. The only thing where I'm a bit uncertain is the storage in ArrowDB. In my Indie plan is **5GB** included (read that somewhere in the pricing plan overview of Appcelerator).

When I force to use ArrowDB in my app than it could be that the storage is filled over time (sooner or later anyway) - but what happens then? If I focus ArrowDB as a backend solution for my platform I'm running into a big problem at this time, because my customers want to use their services and if the cloud storage is full it could block completely...

Does somebody have some experience with that? Does Appcelerator send a mail before the storage reachs the 5GB limit with some additional pricing elements to extend volume of the storage only? How it's handled?

Looking forward to get an answer on that. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

None of our cloud capacity limits are hard limits — the last thing we want to do is shut down your app simply because it was more successful that you originally planned for!  We’ll send you reminders well before you hit 100% of a limit, but should you happen to exceed a limit, we will allow it temporarily and will settle with you after the fact.

Comment: Hi Nathan, thanks a lot for your response! That sounds good, in fact - thanks! :-) Is there anywhere some further pricing table where it's possible to see how additional storage/push-notifications or API calls can be extended and are priced? That would be very interesting and I think it's not the only reason to upgrade the plan...

Comment: Hey @weblion, great question.  Today, we bundle Arrow capabilities and capacity as part of our tiered Appcelerator Platform plans. However, we’ve also been working to introduce Arrow-only plans for greater flexibility. The new Arrow-only plans start at $20 per month and scale from there; these will soon be part of our online pricing.  http://www.appcelerator.com/blog/2016/02/your-very-own-mbaas-how-to-move-from-parse-to-appcelerator-arrow/

Answer (score 0):

Although perhaps there's other users who can share their experience with exceeding limits, this is not really the best place to ask. I suggest you contact Appcelerator sales (http://www.appcelerator.com/contact-us/).